# Which Indexes in which situations is more efficient in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, nonclustered-index

I use SQL Server 2012.

I want know when I want to know in what situation I have to use `CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ....` and in what situation I have to use `Create NonClustered Index... Include` and in what situation I have to use `Create NonClustered Index...` with all columns.

What are the advantage and disadvantage relative to the other

Exemple :

```
Use [AdventureWorksDW2012]
Go

CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX csi_FactResellerSales
ON dbo.FactResellerSales
(ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate);

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
```

[image]

```
Drop Index csi_FactResellerSales On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] 
Create NonClustered Index Ardalan
    On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] (ProductKey) include(UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, 
                                                      OrderDate)

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
```

[image]

```
Drop Index Ardalan On [dbo].[FactResellerSales]
Create NonClustered Index Ardalan1
    On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] (ProductKey,UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate)

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
Drop Index Ardalan1 On [dbo].[FactResellerSales]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are already on the right track here - and I encourage you to keep experimenting with different options and see for yourself what the differences to performance are. But, here are my thoughts below:

**Columnstore Indexes**
These perform really well when you are genuinely interested in all (or most) of the data in a column. If you are keen to see the distribution of data in a column, e.g. number of sales per order or location data, then a column store is a highly performant way to access the whole column.

Writing to columnstore indexes is slower than writing to a row. I would not use a columnstore index if you have a high-velocity OLTP system. Would also avoid columnstore indexes if you are interested in filtering down to small result sets.

**Covering Indexes**
Use these when you have wide tables and queries that regularly access a small number of the columns in the table. Covering indexes are a superb way to remove clustered index scans, reduce your overall IO and improve concurrency.

**Covering indexes over all the columns of a table**
Never. I cannot see a good reason to do this. Am happy to be corrected though.
Perhaps... maybe... still not convinced... you might do this if you are implementing something like a filtered index. This would essentially *chunk* you table into discrete ranges. But I am not convinced this is a good method.